# Stripping dash from parameter name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

An application action receives data via an API connection which sends parameters with dashes in the key

```
  Parameters: { "response-base64"=>"ewogICJwYXltZW50IiA6 [...]
```

thus, when handling the parameters, in this case to decode from base64, rails expectedly trips up after the dash and returns:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `base64'
```

How can the dash be stripped (ignored, or transformed) ONLY from the parameter key (the value may need to hold onto it) ?

Comment: Can you add more context? The code raising the error would be welcome

Comment: I am not certain context would matter. The application is receiving parameters with dashes (clearly a problem) and it needs to work WITHOUT them somehow.

Comment: Try setting `alias_attribute :response-base64, :responsebase64` in your `ActiveRecord` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying this:

```
params[:response-base64]
```

which is not what you expect. Ruby parses sees a subtraction

```
params[ :response - self.base64() ]
```

To access dashed params you can use strings, or quote the symbol name:

```
params['response-base64']
params[:'response-base64']
```